# using $stateProvider with asp.net web api

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am learning angular and web api and stuck a bit with routing. For example I want to display products using the following localhost:53967/products.

My application file is as follow.

```
(function () {

var productListApp = angular.module("productManagement", ["common.services", "ui.router"]);

productListApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");//default url


    $stateProvider.state("productList", {
        url: "/products",
        templateUrl: "app/products/productListView.html",
        controller: "ProductListController"
    })

});
```

})();

I also have an Index.cshtml pageset up as follow.

```
<div class="container">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

WebApiConfig

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
             routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",

            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is my Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);

    }
```

`localhost:53967/products`  returns a 404.
What could be the mistake?

Regards

Comment: Have you ever checked localhost:53967/#/products or localhost:53967/index#/products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> localhost:53967/products returns a 404. What could be the mistake?

You are probably looking for `http://localhost:53967/api/products` instead of `http://localhost:53967/products`. Make sure that you are consistent with your route declarations:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

You've got an `api/` prefix over there, so the client should also respect this.